# CSS / Other templates for Business Web App

Tags: css

I'm working on a scheduling application that will schedule students and staff into classes (and do some other administrative work as well.) It's going to need a web-based UI, and unfortunately I'm not that good at UI design and artistic stuff, so I prefer to work with templates when I can.

I'm looking for CSS templates (or just plain inspiration) of web designs that work for a business app. This is intranet-only, not public facing, and will have lots of lists, dialogs, data grids, menus, etc, but not a lot of text outside of data-bound controls. I'm almost thinking that it should look something like a traditional windows-forms-based app....

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Search in google images:
[http://www.google.com/images?q=interface+design+application](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&source=imghp&biw=1029&bih=553&q=interface+design+application&btnG=Search+Images&gbv=2&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)
[http://www.google.com/images?q=web+design](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&biw=1029&bih=553&gbv=2&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=web+design&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)
[http://www.google.com/images?q=web+design+interface](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&biw=1029&bih=553&gbv=2&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=web+design+interface&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)
[http://www.google.com/images?q=web+application+interface](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&biw=1029&bih=553&gbv=2&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=web+application+interface&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)
[http://www.google.com/images?q=web+ui+interface](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&biw=1029&bih=553&gbv=2&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=web+ui+interface&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)
[http://www.google.com/images?q=web+ui+design](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&biw=1029&bih=553&gbv=2&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=web+ui+design&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

You can also take a look on CSS galleries (result from google search for "css gallery")
http://www.bestcssgallery.com/
http://www.cssheroes.com/
http://www.csselite.com/
http://www.divinecss.com/
http://www.cssbeauty.com/gallery/
http://www.cssdrive.com/

for free css template you can got to:
http://www.free-css-templates.com/
http://www.free-css.com/
http://www.templatemo.com/
http://www.freecsstemplates.org/css-templates/
http://ramblingsoul.com/
(result from google search for "free css template")

you can also take a look at applications for iphone and ipad
http://www.appsites.com/
http://tapfancy.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are not a UI designer, [here](http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php) you can find a nice comparison about web frameworks.
I would recommend you to go for a framework, due the gain of much work on cross-browser stuff and decent defaults and UI.

In my personal experience, I've worked with Twitter Bootstrap on several projects and like it. Since I've used the other frameworks so extensively I cannot (or should not) say it's the best, but at least it fits my requirements and I find pleasing to work with it.
There's a lot of projects integrating these UI frameworks with web frameworks like Django or Rails.

With a simple web search you'll find a lot of themes (free and paid ones), pick what best fits your needs.